# How to suppress unwanted break between consecutive lines?

Tags: line-breaking

I'm writing a journal article (in two-column format), and want to give some results in-text (not as a table or a numbered list), along the lines of:

```
...yields a frequency and semi-amplitude of \\
$\nu_0= 2.1587 (8)$ d$^{-1}$ \\
$a_0=56.5 (25)$ ppm\\
where the bracketed values...
```

Unfortunately, with my current layout the resulting LaTeX output has a column break (which could've been a page break under other circumstances) between the lines of the first and second numerical results -- i.e., the "\nu_0" line is at the foot of one column, and the "a_0" line is at the head of the next.

Is there any way of forcing these two lines to appear contiguously?  (A sort of vertical equivalent of \mbox, i guess?)   Short of a rewrite to avoid the break on an ad hoc basis?

Comment: you surely get errors from `\nu_0= 2.1587 (8)$ d$^{-1}$ `  ? `\nu` must be in math mode

Comment: `\\*` is a forced line break that does not allow a page/column break, but if your document produces errors no pdf is  usable and there is  no guarantee `\\*` will do anything

Comment: In a properly handled document you should never need to use ``\\`` in the text at all.

Comment: @David -- thanks, "\\*" is precisely what i was looking for.   [Sorry about the missing "$", now fixed;  i'd stripped out a lot of additional material to get to the nub of the issue, and didn't do it carefully enough :( ]

Comment: @daleif, i guess you just deprecate \\ over \newline?   Sorry, hard to break old habits...and using \newline doesn't actually change anything

Comment: No you should almost never have either `\\ ` or `\newline` in a document. Also why `d$^{-1}$`  ? why have d in text then a superscript -1 on nothing???? Shouldn't that whole line be a single math expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\\*` is a forced line break that does not allow a page/column break. But usually forced line breaks are an indication that something is wrong, they should be rarely needed in a document.